# how to deserialized the Messagepack data On REST server client

Tags: c++, rest, messagepack, fastcgi++

I am trying to use message pack library t serialize my data in REST server client environment

I and serialize the data using the code below :

```
 std::vector<std::string> target;
    target.push_back("Hello,");
    target.push_back("World!");

    // Serialize it.
    msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;  // simple buffer
    msgpack::pack(&sbuf, target);
```

and sending the data using [fastcgipp](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/doc/2.1/a00003.html) library and send the Output to client using the line :

```
 out << sbuf.data();
```

and the client gets the message but when I try to deresialize it using the code  :

```
     msgpack::sbuffer lineStream(stBinary.length());
                lineStream.write(stBinary.c_str(), stBinary.length());
               msgpack::unpacked msg;    // includes memory pool and deserialized object
                msgpack::unpack(&msg, lineStream.data(), lineStream.size());
               msgpack::object obj = msg.get();

 std::cout <<"OBJECT__" <<obj << std::endl;  //=> ["Hello", "MessagePack"]
```

I get the OUTPUT 
OBJECT__72
and not the expected output which is :

```
["Hello", "MessagePack"]
```

What can be the reason?